# Journey Builder - Unable to see survey result

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, survey

I have created a simple journey in MC with custom data extension as a source.

First step of the journey is to send a welcome email to everyone from my custom DE. I have created and attached custom survey(Created from Email>Content>Surveys). The survey has only one question(radio button).

The journey is sending an email and I can see if the user has opened the welcome email or not but when I navigate to Email>Tracking>email history(Surveys) I am not able to see the result of the survey.

[image]

[image]

What am I missing here? Please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue over a year ago - using Journey Builder to send a survey built in the classic content functionality.  We experienced the same issue of not being to access the survey results through the tracking tab.  After a lot of research and ultimately a case to support, we were told that Surveys tab was not available (at least in tracking) for triggered and/or Journey Builder sends (since all Journey Builder sends are triggered sends).  The suggestion from support (if it wasn't a complex Journey) was to use automation studio to send the email as a user-initiated send.

Ultimately, we ended up writing a number of query activities to move the survey results into a data extension since the journey had already been deployed (hindsight 20/20 moment). This obviously was not ideal for a number of reasons, but we were able to get what we needed.

Lastly, as you probably aware or FYI, the Classic Content functionality (where Surveys are housed) is scheduled for end-of-life (I think sometimes this year).  I don't believe there are plans to move to this functionality to Content Builder - I think there was some conversation about this in the Trailblazer community recently and/or on one of the webinars.  Suggestions were to utilize a third-party survey vendor (e.g. GetFeedback, SurveyMonkey, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have found similar information that this functionality is going to end soon so I have downloaded urveyForce and started using that.
I really appreciate your reply.